# Can a non-nested value be deserialized using a custom Jackson JsonDeserializer?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm working with a project that is using a custom [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) [`JsonDeserializer`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.13.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html) to deserialize an object with a field containing a third-party type from JSON that cannot be deserialized directly.  This deserializer is used by annotating the field with `@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomTypeDeserializer.class)`.

```java
public static class OuterType {
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomTypeDeserializer.class)
    private CustomType customType;

    public CustomType getCustomType() { return customType; }
    public void setCustomType(CustomType customType) { this.customType = customType; }
}
```

This works fine when the type to be deserialized is a property of another type, since there is a place to put the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation.  One thing it does not work for is deserializing the type directly.

```java
new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, CustomType.class); // Doesn't work.
```

It doesn't look like I can use the deserializer directly, as it does not appear to be written in a way that it can directly deserialize values outside of the context of an `ObjectMapper`.

Note that the type to be deserialized is a third-party type, and therefore I cannot modify it with Jackson annotations.

Is there a way to deserialize a non-nested type using a custom deserializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to write a custom [`Module`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.13.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module.html) containing the deserializer to the module, and add the module to the `ObjectMapper`.

```java
public static class CustomTypeModule extends SimpleModule {
    public CustomTypeModule() {
        addDeserializer(CustomType.class, new CustomTypeDeserializer());
    }
}
```

```java
JsonMapper objectMapper = JsonMapper.builder().addModule(new CustomTypeModule()).build();
CustomType value = objectMapper.readValue(json, CustomType.class);
```

If you don't want to modify your global application `ObjectMapper` (making the module available to all requests), you can apply this to a copy of the `ObjectMapper` used just for this operation.

```java
JsonMapper objectMapper = JsonMapper.builder().build();

// ...

JsonMapper customTypeMapper = objectMapper.rebuild().addModule(new CustomTypeModule()).build();
// OR
ObjectMapper customTypeMapper = objectMapper.copy().registerModule(new CustomTypeModule())

CustomType value = customTypeMapper.readValue(json, CustomType.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this were not a third-party type, the type itself could be annotated with the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation.  Since the type is externally controlled and cannot be modified, this approach cannot be used directly.

However, a Jackson mixin can be used to configure the `ObjectMapper` (or a copy of it) to treat the type as though the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation were present on it:

```java
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomTypeDeserializer.class)
public abstract class CustomTypeMixin {}
```

```java
JsonMapper objectMapper = JsonMapper.builder()
        .addMixIn(CustomType.class, CustomTypeMixin.class).build();
CustomType value = objectMapper.readValue(json, CustomType.class));
```

Comment: Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/69582242/1108305 by @dariosicily, which pointed out the possibility of adding `@JsonDeserialize` to a type itself.

Answer (score -1):

If yours possible scenarios guarantee that a custom deserialer will be always applied over your type not considering if it is nested or not you could apply directly the [`JsonDeserialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html) annotation over your `CustomType` class as an alternative to your solution :

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomTypeDeserializer.class)
public class CustomType {}
```

If in your json you want to extract the `CustomType` object you can use the
[`readTree`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readTree(java.lang.String)) and [`treeToValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#treeToValue(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeNode,%20java.lang.Class)) methods :

```
//customType object labelled with "customType"
JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(src).get("customType");
CustomType custom = mapper.treeToValue(tree, CustomType.class);
```

Comment: This is basically what the author wants to *workaround*.

Comment: @VasilyLiaskovsky, the author asked how to deserialize a non-nested type using a custom deserializer and in his answer he registers globally the custom deserializer. I added another method telling how he can directly extract from the json the nested object and this was the other question contained in the post.

Comment: @VasilyLiaskovsky is right.  I mentioned in the question that this was a "third-party object", though it looks like I should have been a bit more explicit about the requirement that the class cannot be modified by me.  I'll update the question to make that more clear and explicit.  That being said, your approach will still work if a mixin is used, so thanks for that bit of inspiration.  I've added an answer using your approach with a mixin — https://stackoverflow.com/a/69592653/1108305.

Comment: @M.Justin No problem, thanks for the clarification.